# Prettyphoto jumps to the top of the page when closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a problem with Prettyphoto with the Qode Bridge theme : when its closed the page jumps to the top. This happens even with a fresh install of Wordpress with Bridge and with no other plugins installed, and also using the latest version of PrettyPhoto (3.1.6).

This problem happens only in Firefox and Internet Explorer. There is no problems with Chrome, Safari or Opera.

The button to close PrettyPhoto is like this :

```
<a class="pp_close" href="#">Close</a>
```

At first I thought it may be a problem because of the # in the href, so I have tried many solutions found here and on the web when searching about this problem but nothing worked :

- replacing href="#" with href="javascript:;"
- replacing href="#" with href="javascript:void(0);" or href="javascript:void();"
- Adding onclick="event.preventDefault();"
- Adding onclick="return false;"

So I'm led to believe that the problem is not within that button (as the problem is only with Firefox and IE), but deeper withing PrettyPhoto's programming.

Is there anyone who knows how to fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem with the following hack...

In the prettyphoto js file, find the following html:

```
<div class="pp_pic_holder">
```

And add this in front of it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var scrollPosition = $("body").scrollTop();</script>
```

Then add the following callback to prettyphoto like this

```
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
    callback: function() {$("html, body").scrollTop(scrollPosition);}
});
```

There is probably a better way to do this other than with inline script, but I couldn't figure out how to run a function when the litebox opened, only when it closed.  So it is kind of a hack workaround, but it validates and works.

Comment: I tried it but when I add the script before <div class="pp_pic_holder"> PrettyPhoto stop working and photos are opened like a normal link.

Comment: I received an update from Qode today and they found a problem inside the Bridge theme and issued a fix.